# Alignment of width of tikz nodes/containers

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to level the width of all the blue dashed containers w.r.t the container with maximum width (container with label 'Outer box 1' in the figure attached).

Also wants to apply the same to container with label 1 w.r.t container with label 2.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
calc,
fit,
positioning,
shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
csbox/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw, thick, 
    minimum height=8mm, minimum width=35mm,
    text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
    align=center
},  
ocbox/.style={
    rectangle,       
    minimum height=8mm, minimum width=28mm,
    text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
    align=center
},      
container/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw, blue, dashed, thick,
    inner sep=3mm, yshift=1mm,
    node contents={}
},      
container2/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw, thick,
    inner sep=3mm, yshift=1mm,
    node contents={}
},      
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=8mm and 4mm,
]

\node (c1) [csbox] {Box 1};
\node (c2) [csbox, left=of c1] {Box 2};
\node (c3) [csbox, right=of c1, , fill=black!20] {Box 3};   
\node (c4) [csbox, right=of c3, , fill=black!20] {Box 4};
\node (container1) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(c1) (c2) (c3) (c4)];
\node (oc1) [ocbox, left=of container1] {Outer Box 1};

\node (d1) [csbox, above=of c1, xshift=2cm] {Box 5};
\node (d3) [csbox, left=of d1, xshift=-1.5cm] {Box 6};
\node (d6) [csbox, right=of d1, fill=black!20, xshift=1.5cm] {Box 7};
\node (container2) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(d1) (d3) (d6)];
\node (oc2) [ocbox, left=of container2] {Outer Box 2};

\node (v1) [csbox, above=of d1] {Box 8};
\node (v2) [csbox, above=of d3] {Box 9};
\node (v3) [csbox, above=of d6, fill=black!20] {Box 10};
\node (container3) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(v1) (v2) (v3)];
\node (oc3) [ocbox, left=of container3] {Outer Box 3};

\node (n1) [csbox, below left=of c4, xshift=1.5cm, minimum width=45mm] {Box 11};
\node (n2) [csbox, below right=of c2, xshift=-1.5cm] {Box 12};  
\node (container4) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(n1)(n2)];
\node (oc4) [ocbox, left=of container4] {Outer Box 4};

\node (u1) [csbox, above=of v1] {Box 13};
\node (u2) [csbox, above=of v2] {Box 14};
\node (u3) [csbox, above=of v3, fill=black!20] {Box 15};
\node (container5) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(u1) (u2) (u3)];
\node (oc5) [ocbox, left=of container5] {Outer Box 5};  

\node (ooc1)[container2,yshift=-1mm, fit=(container1) (container2) (container3) (container4) (container5) (oc1) (oc2) (oc3) (oc4) (oc5)];

\node (s1) [csbox, above=of ooc1, minimum width=60mm,xshift=1.5cm] {Box 16};
\node (container6) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(s1)];
\node (oc6) [ocbox, left=of container6] {Outer Box 6};

\node (s1) [csbox, above=of s1,xshift=-1.5cm] {Box 16};
\node (s2) [csbox, left=of s1] {Box 17};
\node (s3) [csbox, right=of s1,minimum width=15mm] {....};
\node (s4) [csbox, right=of s3, minimum width=45mm] {Box 18};
\node (container7) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(s1) (s2) (s3) (s4)];
\node (oc7) [ocbox, left=of container7] {Outer Box 18};

\node (ooc2)[container2,yshift=-1mm, fit=(container6) (container7) (oc6) (oc7)];

\node[below right, inner sep=5pt] at (ooc2.north west) {label1};
\node[below right, inner sep=5pt] at (ooc1.north west) {label2};

\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I did only "code repairing". I just introduced yet another container, fitting your your containers, which I do not draw. And then I use the left and right extrema of this additional container to make the container nodes have the same widths. And instead of some of your `oc` nodes I just use labels. And I use lists and `\foreach` in order to not write the same things over and over.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14mm]{standalone} % margin=3mm is wrong ;-)
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
calc,
fit,
positioning,
shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
csbox/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw, thick, 
    minimum height=8mm, minimum width=35mm,
    text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
    align=center
},  
ocbox/.style={
    rectangle,       
    minimum height=8mm, minimum width=28mm,
    text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
    align=center
},      
container/.style={% we don't draw them any more but use them for bookkeeping
    rectangle,opacity=0, 
    %draw, blue, dashed, thick,
    inner sep=3mm, yshift=1mm,outer sep=0pt,
    node contents={}
},      
container2/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw, thick,
    inner sep=3mm, yshift=1mm,
    node contents={}
},
fake box/.style={inner sep=0pt,node contents={}},
true container/.style={
    draw, blue, dashed, thick,
    inner sep=3mm, yshift=1mm,inner sep=0pt,
    node contents={},label={[align=right,name=oc\X]left:#1}
},     
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=8mm and 4mm,
]

\node (c1) [csbox] {Box 1};
\node (c2) [csbox, left=of c1] {Box 2};
\node (c3) [csbox, right=of c1, , fill=black!20] {Box 3};   
\node (c4) [csbox, right=of c3, , fill=black!20] {Box 4};
\node (container1) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(c1) (c2) (c3) (c4)];
%\node (oc1) [ocbox, left=of container1] {Outer Box 1};

\node (d1) [csbox, above=of c1, xshift=2cm] {Box 5};
\node (d3) [csbox, left=of d1, xshift=-1.5cm] {Box 6};
\node (d6) [csbox, right=of d1, fill=black!20, xshift=1.5cm] {Box 7};
\node (container2) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(d1) (d3) (d6)];
%\node (oc2) [ocbox, left=of container2] {Outer Box 2};

\node (v1) [csbox, above=of d1] {Box 8};
\node (v2) [csbox, above=of d3] {Box 9};
\node (v3) [csbox, above=of d6, fill=black!20] {Box 10};
\node (container3) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(v1) (v2) (v3)];
%\node (oc3) [ocbox, left=of container3] {Outer Box 3};

\node (n1) [csbox, below left=of c4, xshift=1.5cm, minimum width=45mm] {Box 11};
\node (n2) [csbox, below right=of c2, xshift=-1.5cm] {Box 12};  
\node (container4) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(n1)(n2)];
%\node (oc4) [ocbox, left=of container4] {Outer Box 4};

\node (u1) [csbox, above=of v1] {Box 13};
\node (u2) [csbox, above=of v2] {Box 14};
\node (u3) [csbox, above=of v3, fill=black!20] {Box 15};
\node (container5) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(u1) (u2) (u3)];
%\node (oc5) [ocbox, left=of container5] {Outer Box 5};  


\xdef\Lst{}
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{\xdef\Lst{\Lst (container\X)}}
\node (phantom) [fake box,fit=\Lst];
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{\node [true container={Outer box \X\\ another line},fit=(container\X) (phantom.west |- container\X.center)
(phantom.east |- container\X.center)];}

\node (ooc1)[container2,yshift=-1mm, fit=(container1) (container2) (container3) (container4) (container5) (oc1) (oc2) (oc3) (oc4) (oc5)];

%upper part
\node (s1) [csbox, above=of ooc1, minimum width=60mm,xshift=1.5cm] {Box 16};
\node (container6) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(s1)];
%\node (oc6) [ocbox, left=of container6] {Outer Box 6};

\node (s1) [csbox, above=of s1,xshift=-1.5cm] {Box 16};
\node (s2) [csbox, left=of s1] {Box 17};
\node (s3) [csbox, right=of s1,minimum width=15mm] {....};
\node (s4) [csbox, right=of s3, minimum width=45mm] {Box 18};
\node (container7) [container,yshift=-1mm, fit=(s1) (s2) (s3) (s4)];
%\node (oc7) [ocbox, left=of container7] {Outer Box 18};

\xdef\Lst{}
\foreach \X in {6,7}
{\xdef\Lst{\Lst (container\X)}}
\node (phantom) [fake box,fit=\Lst];
\foreach \X in {6,7}
{\node [true container={Outer box \X},fit=(container\X) (phantom.west |- container\X.center)
(phantom.east |- container\X.center)];}

\node (ooc2)[container2,yshift=-1mm, fit=(container6) (container7) (oc6) (oc7)];

%OK
\node[below right, inner sep=5pt] at (ooc2.north west) {label1};
\node[below right, inner sep=5pt] at (ooc1.north west) {label2};

\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would actually like to encourage you to develop a strategy *before* starting to write so much code with so much repetition. This will make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but brought new complications. Now, I need to break lines in labels and used all possible solutions but couldn't.

Comment: Just do `label={[name=oc\X,align=left]left:#1}`, i.e. add `align=left` (or `align=center` or `text width=...`....

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replies and help. I really appreciate it